# How can we check the installed sanner driver is 32bit or 64bit on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, scanner, c#

How can we check the installed scanner driver is 32bit or 64bit on Windows 10 Professional (64 bit)?

There are 3 scanners attached with my PC.
If I run TWAIN Twacker (32 bit) tool. then all 3 scanners shows in list
and If I run TWAIN Twacker (64 bit) tool then no scanners shows.

My question is, why these scanner is not showing to TWAIN Twacker (64 bit)?
Does it mean, there are only 32 bit Twain drivers installed and Twain twacker 64 bit can't read 32 bit driver devices?

**Why I need this**

  *I am working on .NET application that need to read these scanners. So when I run my application as 64 bit, it can't read these scanners and if I run my application as 32 bit then it can read all these 3. I have to deploy my application as 64 bit*

You can see details of  TWAIN Twacker tool from following URLs 
http://www.twain.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Twack-64.msi
https://developer.dynamsoft.com/dwt/kb/2644

I have also done testing on Windows 7 professional (64 bit) and got same results

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to figure out if the twain driver you have installed is a 32 bit or 64 bit is to check where the .ds file for the driver is at. If its in the C:windows/twain_32 folder it is a 32 bit driver or if its in the C:windows/twain_64 folder it is a 64 bit driver. Twack 64 will only pick up drivers in the C:windows/twain_64 folder. So the drivers you have installed are most likely twain 32 bit drivers.